# Connect SendObserver to ISendEndpoint obtained by consume context once

Tags: masstransit

I am trying to observe sent messages using SendObserver on an ISendEndpoint. When I use GetSendEndpoint from the consume context and add the observer using ConnectSendObserver I notice that the previous observers added from previous messages still exist, so the observer is called multiple times after the first message is sent.
Please note that I have to set the observer through the consume context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the `ConnectHandle` returned when the observer is connected to disconnect the observer once the sent messages have been observed. In your case, once the `ConsumeContext` is no longer being used - such as at the end of the consumer.

That way, you don't accumulate them over time.